# What do I need to add to turn (or offset) dog poop into fertilizer?

Tags: compost, dog

We end up with dog poop in our yard.

I'd like to put pour something on it that would break it down/compost it  (even if it took a month).   I'd rather not have to pick it up :)
Bonus points if there's something simple with active microbes to hasten the process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nobody like picking up dog poo, so much that there was a comedy movie based on your idea: [VaPOOrize](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpads8s5mik)

Comment: What ever is beneath the poo will die.  You have to get it off your lawn.  Plant beds not so much.  I would put a little stand offering latex gloves and/or plastic bags asking nicely for dog walkers to pick up their own POO.  Best thing to break down and add to the decomposition process is NITROGEN.  Alfalfa pellets meant for kitty litter are fabulous.  Decomposers need nitrogen to do their work of decomposing.

Comment: There are great scooper upper thingies for poop.  There are also these 'composters' made just for dog poop.  Like a little silo in the soil, just dump the poo in and forget it.  I would add sawdust and have a way to remove the composted doggie poo easily.  Do not use on your edibles.  All other garden spaces your plants will love this stuff, after decomposed fully.  My favorite mulch is human poo mixed with sawdust and completely decomposed at the city utilities for sewage and tested (in the states by the feds) 5X.  You know exactly what is in that mulch.  A little too much heavy metals to eat

Comment: @stormy Your answer is what I'm looking for. However, I realized I should have phrased it more clearly. I reposted for YOU to answer:  https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39703/what-treatments-would-balance-out-whats-in-dog-poo-on-my-lawn-to-not-kill-th

Comment: @stormy Would kitty litter work as a nitrogen source?

Comment: Only kitty litter made of alfalfa pellets...no other.  Great nitrogen source for the decomposers.  Not to be a source of fertilizer.  Even though it is Nitrogen you need  to know the percentages of the big three.  NPK.  I'll go check your repost!

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/composting/manures/dog-waste-in-compost.htm,  dog feces is difficult to compost because it contains parasites that can be harmful.  You would maintain a temperature of 165F or 73C for 5 days in order to kill them.

It is recommended that you mix it with 1 part sawdust to 2 parts feces, cover with black plastic and leave in the sun.

Comment: This dog poo composting is only contraindicated when adding to veggies or edible crops.  Brian's recipe is great except use clear plastic, not black.  This is solarization.  Just don't use the compost for stuff you want to eat.

Comment: Solarization happens with clear plastic, not black.  Common misconception.  Dog, cat or any poo poo is great to use for ornamentals, not for vegetables.  When one checks out the heavy metals and disgusting other elements in tap water well, I am on the verge of using DECOMPOSED sawdust and poo for my edibles.  Not just yet.

Comment: Would mulched browned leave work as a substitute for the sawdust?