# What treatments would "balance out" what's in dog poo on my lawn, to not kill the lawn?

Tags: compost, dog

Criteria:

1. I do not want to MOVE the poop.
2. I just want to keep it from killing the grass
3. I'm ok with it taking 1-3 weeks to break down.
4. I'm looking for *easy* not perfect :)

I know: *we should be picking up the poo* and tossing it into a compost bin (or the garbage). I don't have the time to do that regularly (and we have to "active" dogs :).  The dog poo is not getting picked up regularly. **Not a solution** in the near future.

But I do think I could manage to go out and spray/pour something over it.

Comment: The time it takes to pour something on the poo to allow it to disintegrate or decompose faster is the same amount of time to just fling it off the shovel into the bushes. That bulk will cause the grass beneath to die within days.  Take a shovel and fling away into the bushes or a handy 5 gallon bucket.  What kind of dogs do you have?  I've got two gnarly chocolate lab/blue heeler boys!  We did not think they would get so dang big.  I just buried my last two labs who were huge, these showed up in the arms of friends at 4 weeks old.  So tiny.

Comment: Poop is easy to go collect before you mow the grass.  Part of the routine.  Or...get a taste when you use the weed wacker.  Grins.  Ugh.  I am used to slug guts as well.  Dogs need heavy exercise.  Not just lollygagging in a fenced yard or a walk around the block.  I am furiously working on dog carting or dog sledding.  Sadly, there is nothing to pour on dog poo to make it disappear. Do you have time to work with your dogs?  We also have a dog pen, no lawn to worry about; 35X25 feet.  This in no way replaces walks, one on one workouts.  Just a bit better than chained up.

Comment: By the tine the decomposers disintegrate the poo, the grass will have died beneath the poo because NO LIGHT.  Too much raw poo and nitrogen will burn a grass crop that is healthy.  A not healthy and fertilized lawn those spots will green up big time. It is easier, faster, straight forward to just scoop the poop IF you want a healthy lawn.  There is nothing you can pour on the poo to make it disappear before it has harmed a spot on your lawn.  I've made dog pens to have an easy to maintain grass area otherwise the rest was crushed gravel installed 4" deep, compacted and LS fabric beneath.

Comment: Also made sure the drainage was perfect beneath the gravels so one could hose everything down.  Lawn is a luxury.  Lawns are not meant for use by dogs on a regular basis.

Comment: @stormy  - "that poo... easy to collect" . Will you come by *my house* and do that <grin>. Seriously, the "fling into bushes with shovel" is a pretty good idea.
(I know it seems silly, but gathering the bucket, then cleaning it afterwards just...doesn't get done).

Comment: I also have 2 very very large chocolate lab crosses.  Built a 35X40 foot pen for them with 8 foot high wire fencing.  We take a rake once a month and rake it into a pile and allow it to decompose.  Throwing it into the bushes is a great way to allow the poop to decompose.  No bucket involved.  There are cylinders that you set into your beds here and there in which to dump the fresh poop.  This allows the poop to decompose out of sight, pick up the cylinder out of the ground and spread on the back of plant beds or dump at the dump.  Still lots of stuff to do.  Are you that thinly spread?